# Add language to relationship dropdown in ExpressionEngine

Tags: php, relationship, expressionengine, backend

I'm using ExpressionEngine for a multi-language website with products. I used [Transcribe](http://eeharbor.com/transcribe) for controlling the multi-language. Products have the same title in different languages, and this gives me some problems selecting the correct product in a relationship field.

The builder of this site did not use the `title` for a unique name in the back-end only, but also displayed it everywhere in the front-end.

Dropdown example:

- Product A
- Product A
- Product A
- Product B
- Product B
- Product B
- Product c
- Product c
- Product c

I found that the dropdown information is filled in `/system/expressionengine/fieldtypes/rel/ft.rel.php` from line 59

```
/**
 * Display Relationship Field
 *
 * @access  public
 * @param   string
 * @return  string
 */

function display_field($data)
{
    if ($this->settings['field_related_orderby'] == 'date')
    {
        $this->settings['field_related_orderby'] = 'entry_date';
    }

    $this->EE->db->select('entry_id, title');
    $this->EE->db->where('channel_id', $this->settings['field_related_id']);
    $this->EE->db->order_by($this->settings['field_related_orderby'], $this->settings['field_related_sort']);

    if ($this->settings['field_related_max'] > 0)
    {
        $this->EE->db->limit($this->settings['field_related_max']);
    }

    $relquery = $this->EE->db->get('channel_titles');

    if ($relquery->num_rows() == 0)
    {
        return $this->EE->lang->line('no_related_entries');
    }
    else
    {
        if ( ! isset($_POST[$this->field_name]))
        {
            $this->EE->db->select('rel_child_id');
            $relentry = $this->EE->db->get_where('relationships', array('rel_id' => $data));

            if ($relentry->num_rows() == 1)
            {
                $data = $relentry->row('rel_child_id') ;
            }
        }

        $field_options[''] = '--';

        foreach ($relquery->result_array() as $relrow)
        {
            $field_options[$relrow['entry_id']] = $relrow['title'];
        }
        return form_dropdown($this->field_name, $field_options, $data, 'id="field_id_'.$this->field_id.'"');
    }
}
```

How can I add the language name to the dropdown at line 98 `($field_options[$relrow['entry_id']] = $relrow['title'];)`?

Comment: If your question is not getting the attention you feel it needs here i recommend you post it to http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'm not familiar with the data structure of Transcribe. Does it add columns to the channel_titles table? If so, what is are the name of these columns and which one(s) would you want to append to the dropdown list?

Comment: Transcribe adds multiple tables where the data is linked with each other. I will try the stackexchange from EE and try to contact with the Transcribe team.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Transcribe did not found any possibilities in Expression Engine 2.5.
I created a workaround and added the url_title in the dropdown menu. It is not the best solution, but in this case it is workable.

```
$this->EE->db->select('entry_id, title');
```

changed into

```
$this->EE->db->select('entry_id, title, url_title');
```

And changed

```
$field_options[$relrow['entry_id']] = $relrow['title'];
```

into

```
$field_options[$relrow['entry_id']] = $relrow['title'] . " - " . $relrow['url_title'];
```